# Как оптимизировать код JS

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

сделал простой калькулятор, который складывает, вычитает, умножает и делит.
Но как этот код уменьшить? На сколько я понимаю это делается с помощью функций, но я не понимаю как это реализовать.

```js
function plus() {
      
      var num1, num2, result;
      num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
      num1 = parseInt(num1);
    
      num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
      num2 = Number(num2);
    
      result = num1 + num2;
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = result;
    }
    
    function minus() {
      var num1, num2, result;
      num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
      num1 = parseInt(num1);
    
      num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
      num2 = Number(num2);
    
      result = num1 - num2;
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = result;
    }
    
    function multiply() {
      var num1, num2, result;
      num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
      num1 = parseInt(num1);
    
      num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
      num2 = Number(num2);
    
      result = num1 * num2;
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = result;
    
    }
    
    function share() {
      var num1, num2, result;
      num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
      num1 = parseInt(num1);
    
      num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
      num2 = Number(num2);
    
      result = num1 / num2;
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = result;
    }
```

```html
        <h1>калкулятор</h1>
        <div class="NumAll">
            <p class="Num1" >
                
                <input type="text" id="n1">
                
            </p>
            <p class="Num2" >
                <input type="text" id="n2">
            </p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="btn">
    
            <button onclick="minus()" >Вычесть</button>
    
            <button onclick="plus()" >Сложить</button>
    
            <button onclick="multiply()" >Умножить</button>
    
            <button onclick="share()" >Делить</button>
    
        </div>
        
        <p class="Res" id="out">Результат</p>
```

Comment: У вас калькулятор реализован с помощью функций.

Comment: Я понимаю, но я хочу сделать так, что бы каждый раз не нужно было писать : num1 = num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
      num1 = parseInt(num1);
    
      num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
      num2 = Number(num2);

Comment: Добавьте функцию, которая будет вычитывать значения `n1`, `n2` из html и записывать в переменные

Comment: Я когда писал по приколу калькулятор, я использовал [`eval()`](https://learn.javascript.ru/eval)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все четыре функции у вас отличаются лишь операцией. Логично будет сделать функцию, которая получает два числа, тип операции и возвращает результат. А получение и вывод данных прописать лишь в одном месте.

`document.querySelector(селектор)` возвращает первый элемент на странице, который будет соответствовать CSS-селектору. Если и его не хочется дублировать везде, можно сделать коротенькую функцию-обертку и для него.

Вынес `onclick` из HTML, потому что оно не используется дальше учебных примеров ( https://google.com#q=dont+use+inline+onclick ). Хорошо бы сразу привыкнуть к addEventListener — добавлять обработчики отдельно от HTML.

```js
let inp_1 = first("#n1"), inp_2 = first("#n2"), out = first("#out");

first(".btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let operation = e.target.dataset.oper;  
  if (!operation) return; // Операция не указана? Значит кликнули не на кнопку.
  
  let a = +inp_1.value; // унарный плюс делает то же, что и Number()
  let b = +inp_2.value;
  
  out.textContent = calc(a, operation, b);
});

/***/
function calc(a, oper, b) {  
  switch (oper) {
    case "sub": return a - b;
    case "sum": return a + b;
    case "mul": return a * b;
    case "div": return a / b;
  }
}

function first(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}
```

```html
<h1>калкулятор</h1>
<div class="NumAll">
  <p class="Num1">
    <input type="text" id="n1">
  </p>
  <p class="Num2">
    <input type="text" id="n2">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="btn">
  <button data-oper="sub">Вычесть</button>
  <button data-oper="sum">Сложить</button>
  <button data-oper="mul">Умножить</button>
  <button data-oper="div">Делить</button>
</div>

<p class="Res" id="out">Результат</p>
```

Comment: * sub, mul, div ←→ subtract, multiply, divide

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ! Я еще на начальной стадии изучения js, подчерпнул много нового )

Answer (score 3):

Можно определить класс с множеством допустимых операторов.

```js
class Calc {
  binary_operators = {
    '+': (a, b) => a + b,
    '-': (a, b) => a - b,
    '*': (a, b) => a * b,
    '/': (a, b) => a / b,
  };
  unary_operators = {
    'sin': (a) => Math.sin(a),
  };
  constructor(aEl, bEl, resEl) {
    this.aEl = aEl;
    this.bEl = bEl;
    this.resEl = resEl;
  }
  initButtons(buttons) {
    buttons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (btn.dataset.binOperator) {
        this.binaryOp(btn.dataset.binOperator);
      } else if (btn.dataset.unaryOperator) {
        this.unaryOp(btn.dataset.unaryOperator);
      }
    }));
  }
  unaryOp(op) {
    const operator = this.unary_operators[op];
    if (!operator) throw new Error(`Unknown operator ${op}`);

    this.resEl.innerText = operator(+this.aEl.value);
  }
  binaryOp(op) {
    const operator = this.binary_operators[op];
    if (!operator) throw new Error(`Unknown operator ${op}`);

    this.resEl.innerText = operator(+this.aEl.value, +this.bEl.value);
  }
}
const calc = new Calc(
  document.getElementById('n1'),
  document.getElementById('n2'),
  document.getElementById('out')
);
calc.initButtons(document.querySelectorAll('.calc-button'));
```

```html
<h1>Калькулятор</h1>
<div class="NumAll">
  <p class="Num1">
    <input type="text" id="n1">
  </p>
  <p class="Num2">
    <input type="text" id="n2">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="btn">
  <button data-bin-operator="-" class="calc-button">Вычесть</button>
  <button data-bin-operator="+" class="calc-button">Сложить</button>
  <button data-bin-operator="*" class="calc-button">Умножить</button>
  <button data-bin-operator="/" class="calc-button">Делить</button>
  <button data-unary-operator="sin" class="calc-button">sin(x)</button>
</div>

<p class="Res" id="out">Результат</p>
```

---

<sub>*А это кое-кому похоже нечем было заняться перед концом рабочей недели)*</sub>

```js
class Calc {
  operations = {
    'id': (a, b) => b,
     '+': (a, b) => a + b,
     '-': (a, b) => a - b,
     '*': (a, b) => a * b,
     '/': (a, b) => a / b,
  };
  unary_operators = {
    'sin': (a) => Math.sin(a),
  };
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el;
    this.resEl = this.el.querySelector('.calc-result');
    this.initialize();
    this.reset();
  }
  reset() {
    this.resEl.innerText = '0';
    this.operandA = 0;
    this.operandB = 0;
    this.newInputFlag = true;
    this.currentOperator = this.operations['id'];
  }
  #calc() {
    const result = this.currentOperator(this.operandA, this.operandB);

    this.operandA = result;
    this.resEl.innerText = parseFloat(result.toFixed(16));
    this.newInputFlag = true;
  }
  #addDigit(digit) {
    if (this.newInputFlag) {
      this.resEl.innerText = '';
    }
    this.resEl.innerText = (this.resEl.innerText + digit).replace(/^0+(\d)/, '$1');
    this.newInputFlag = false;
  }
  #addPoint() {
    if (this.newInputFlag) {
      this.resEl.innerText = '0';
    }
    if (-1 === this.resEl.innerText.indexOf('.')) {
      this.resEl.innerText = this.resEl.innerText + '.';
      this.newInputFlag = false;
    }
  }
  #getResult() {
    try {
      if (!this.newInputFlag) {
        this.operandB = Number(this.resEl.innerText);
      }
      this.#calc();
    } catch (e) {
      this.resEl.innerText = 'ЕГГОГ';
    }
  }
  #setOperator(operator) {
    if (!this.newInputFlag) {
      this.operandB = Number(this.resEl.innerText);
      this.#calc();
    }

    if (!operator) throw new Error(`Unknown operation ${op}`);
    this.currentOperator = operator;
  }
  #initButton(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      switch (btn.dataset.calcType) {
        case 'reset':    this.reset(); break;
        case 'digit':    this.#addDigit(btn.dataset.digit); break;
        case 'point':    this.#addPoint(); break;
        case 'result':   this.#getResult(); break;
        case 'operator': this.#setOperator(this.operations[btn.dataset.calcOp]); break;
      }
    });
  }
  initialize() {
    this.el.querySelectorAll('.calc-button')
      .forEach(btn => this.#initButton(btn));
  }
}
const calc = new Calc(document.querySelector('.calc'));
```

```css
.calc {
  border: 3px solid silver;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #cec;
}
.calc-result {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  background: #aaa;

  text-align: right;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 2em;

  white-space: nowrap;
}
table.calc-buttons {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
}
table.calc-buttons td .calc-button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <div class="calc-result">0</div>
    <table class="calc-buttons">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="reset">C</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="operator" data-calc-op="/">/</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="operator" data-calc-op="*">*</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="operator" data-calc-op="-">-</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="digit" data-digit="7">7</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="digit" data-digit="8">8</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="digit" data-digit="9">9</button>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="operator" data-calc-op="+">+</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="digit" data-digit="4">4</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="digit" data-digit="5">5</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="digit" data-digit="6">6</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="digit" data-digit="1">1</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="digit" data-digit="2">2</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="digit" data-digit="3">3</button>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="result">=</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="digit" data-digit="0">0</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="calc-button" data-calc-type="point">.</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Не думаю что стоит новичку впихивать классы.. Хотя..

Comment: Почему нет-то? Неужто лучше завалить новичка миллионом функций и переменных?

Comment: Не говорю, что это плохо.. Но считаю, что это как учить Bootstrap, не зная CSS.. jQuery, не зная JS и т.п. Как-то так. Азы надо знать, хотя бы поверхностно, имхо.

Comment: Класс в js - это и есть азы, наравне с переменными и функциями)

Answer (score 2):

P.S. `eval()` лучше не использовать с связи с безопасностью, но в нашем случаи `+document...value` возвратит либо число, либо `NaN`.

**UPD**
Вместо `eval` можно использовать синтаксис `Function(...)`.

```js
const out = document.getElementById('out');

function calc(operation) {
  out.innerHTML = Function(`return (${+document.getElementById('n1').value} ${operation} ${+document.getElementById('n2').value})`)()
}
```

```html
<h1>калкулятор</h1>
<div class="NumAll">
  <p class="Num1">
    <input type="text" id="n1">
  </p>
  <p class="Num2">
    <input type="text" id="n2">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="btn">
  <button onclick="calc('-')">Вычесть</button>
  <button onclick="calc('+')">Сложить</button>
  <button onclick="calc('*')">Умножить</button>
  <button onclick="calc('/')">Делить</button>
</div>

<p class="Res" id="out">Результат</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Function кстати тот же eval по сути, только под другим именем)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, на mdn писало, что Function чем-то там более оптимальный...